# youtube video feed

Tags: feeds, files

I'm new to Drupal and what I want to accomplish is a youtube video feed like the one on the [Dalai Lama's website](http://www.dalailama.com/webcasts) I know I can get an atom, rss, or json-c feed of my desired youtube playlist. What steps do I take next to create the page that has the list and hook it up to a page with the embedded youtube video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) module and create Media files using that module with [Media Youtube](http://drupal.org/project/media_youtube), there will be some configurations so you have to do them by your own.

Answer (score 0):

HTML parser and can fetch data from existing URLs.
Feeds is the way to go fetch rss feeds.

Modules required to fetch youtube feeds

1.Feeds it import's or aggregate's data as node, users, taxonomy terms or simple database records.

2.Youtube feeds, this module adds a new parser for Feeds module that makes it possible to parse and import YouTube video feeds

3.Youtube pull is a simple module to pull YouTube feed for latest video listing.This module is optional.

4.Feeds Tamper provides a small plugin architecture for Feeds to modify data before it gets saved.This module is used as per requirement.

Download and install the modules mentioned above. Configure the feeds module as per requirement. While configuring ,fields mapping plays a crucial role .Mapping helps to map current node field with the new nodes created from feeds. Use the YouTube API Tool to get the right URL! Once configuration is done you are all set to import feeds.